# Install Centos 7 or Ubuntu 14.04 on HP DL160 G6

Tags: ubuntu, raid, hp, hp-proliant, centos7

I have recently bought a couple of 2nd hand HP DL160 G6.
I have configured the internal B110i in RAID 1+0 (using four SATA disks). 
When I tried to install either Centos 7 or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the machines I have seen all the four drives independently rather than the created array. 
I used in the past HP DL380 G5 which had a cciss driver that was recognized by either distro (RHEL 5 and Ubuntu 12.04).

How Can I enable the array on the machine (at install time if possible)?

Do I have to provide some custom driver (using dd install)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that particular server, there is a binary driver (hpahcisr, *not* cciss or hpsa) available for [supported operating systems](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3958194) (Windows, RHEL6, SuSE); neither of which you're planning to use.

In the case of Ubuntu or anything other than RHEL5/6, your only options are a different controller or to use [software RAID](https://access.redhat.com/articles/118133). Ubuntu is totally unsupported on this platform.

*Here's HP's compatibility matrix for the ProLiant DL160 G6*
[image]

Comment: Is there any operation that I have to do in BIOS (e.g delete logical disks, disable RAID/RAID controller) before setting up the software RAID? Or shall I create 4 devices in raid 0?

Comment: The OS won't even recognize that controller without the driver. You'll be disabling the RAID functionality completely.